# How to resolve a PHP regex search and replace which breaks when adding single quote inside single quoted strings?

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on a PHP project that was recently upgraded from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.2. After the upgrade, we've been seeing warnings related to array keys that are not enclosed in quotes.

In PHP 7.2, the E_WARNING error level was raised for cases where array keys were not enclosed in quotes. Specifically, when a string literal or an unquoted string is used as an array key, PHP 7.2 issues a warning similar to the following:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant mykey - assumed 'mykey' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

The warning message indicates that the string "myKey" is being treated as a constant, which may lead to errors in the future. This warning was introduced as part of the effort to make PHP code more reliable and to prevent common sources of errors.

To address this, I found a regex that can identify and fix array keys that are not wrapped in quotes and replaces the content of the array keys with single quotes:

```
$fileContent = preg_replace('/^!|\$([a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)\[([a-zA-Z_][a-z0-9_]+)\]/','\$$1[\'$2\']', $fileContent, -1, $c1);
```

However, I noticed that the regex matches array keys that are within single quoted strings and causes a syntax error after wrapping it in single quotes. For example:

before : `'some string $var[testkey4]; around the var';`

after : `'some string $var['testkey4']; around the var'; syntax error, unexpected 'testkey4' (T_STRING)`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Yeah this isn't something that you're going to fix via regex. Either you need something to parse PHP's syntax and apply the fixes, or you do it by hand. So you're going to need to do it by hand. This is not a problem that was _new_ in 7.2, you've just been ignoring the log messages about it... probably as long as this codebase has existed.

Comment: Can you explain why regex could not fix this ? I don't mind restricting the pattern even more to the point of excluding variables found withing string quotes if it means I can save myself a few hours of manual work. Also I do plan to go over the changes anyway to make sure it all looks good aswell.

Comment: Can you just run [PHP Stan](https://phpstan.org/r/4c7c9230-046f-40b2-b5b0-e60542a4740d) at it instead?

Comment: Otherwise, if you really want to go RegEx, I’d go line-by-line. If the line doesn’t contain a bracket, skip. If it does, then count opening and closing and if they don’t match, log not-fixed and skip (this is to handle multiple lines). If the line has a single quote before a bracket, log not fixed and skip (could be interpolation, concatenation, etc.). Repeat with additional items you might find. Then maybe a blind RegEx might work on that line. Escaped brackets and quotes, such as your RegEx itself, add some fun, too.

Comment: Because regular expressions are bad at nested syntax, like quotes inside quotes or matching braces, and escaped escapes. Regular expressions are good at matching rigid, one-dimensional syntax, and PHP source is not that.